# Unable to read data from the transport connection (Bing Maps Api)

Tags: c#, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm doing Batch Reverse Geocoding, and sometimes I got the below error after the job is completed.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Which side is causing this error and how it can be solved?

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't seen/heard of this error before, so I want to lean towards the issue being on your side. I'll pass this thread on to our dev team to see if they have seen it before, and if so, will report back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with the dev team and they said the following:

> For batch geocoding, this is mostly due to the network connectivity
>   was interrupted or closed on the client side when the customer is
>   trying to upload the files. The upload can take time so it is better
>   to have the client side to use the HttpWebRequest instead of the
>   WebRequest to have the KeepAlive set to true to keep the connection
>   open.